# Data persistence in a multi-page Dash app

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Dash app where user in one page, `data.py`, adds some data, and later selected  rows can be viewed and removed on another page, `grid.py`. The user should be able to later get back to `data.py` and add some more data.

The problem: data is not persisted between the visits to the `grid.py`. How can I achieved that? I tried setting `persistence` property, but that didn't get me anywhere. `existing_data` in `grid.py` is always `None`. When I use a single-page app, similar code works.

Here's my minimal reproducible example:

**app.py**

```
from dash import html, dcc
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id="store", data={}),
        html.H1("Multi Page App Demo: Sharing data between pages"),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    dcc.Link(f"{page['name']}", href=page["path"]),
                )
                for page in dash.page_registry.values()
            ]
        ),
        html.Hr(),
        dash.page_container,
    ]
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**data.py**

```
from dash import html, Input, Output, callback, register_page
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import random

register_page(__name__, path="/")


layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H3("Data input"),
        html.Button("Add row", id="button_id"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id="my-output"),
    ]
)


@callback(
    [Output("store", "data"), Output("my-output", "children")],
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def add_data(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        new_data = [{"col1": "New row", "col2": random.randint(0, 1000)}]
        return new_data, html.Pre(str(new_data))
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

**grid.py**

```
from dash import html, dash_table, Input, Output, callback, register_page, State


register_page(__name__)


layout = html.Div([
    html.H3("Data tables"),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id="table",
        row_deletable=True,
        column_selectable="single",
        page_size=5,
        persistence=True,
        persisted_props=[
            "data",
            "columns.name",
            "filter_query",
            "hidden_columns",
            "page_current",
            "selected_columns",
            "selected_rows",
            "sort_by",
        ],
    ),
])


@callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    Input("store", "data"),
    State("table", "data"),
)
def update(new_data, existing_data):
    if existing_data is not None:
        return existing_data + new_data
    else:
        return new_data
```

Comment: I had a similar requirement for Flask app -- I achieved that by having a POST query between the pages, and they'd always "communicate" with each other by sending the data. Do you think this concept would be a solution for you?

Comment: I can't tell for certain unless I try, so if you could provide some details around that, it would be welcomed! Can be as an answer, maybe we could make it together into a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out two ways of doing it:

1. Shared `Store` component.
2. Using a persistent component feature from [dash_extensions.pages](https://www.dash-extensions.com/sections/pages).

I am going to share both for completeness. One reason for having (2) is that I do not fully understand why (1) works, as to my knowledge it introduces a circular dependency. The latter should throw an exception or, worse, result in an infinite callback cycle, which it doesn't. That's smart on behalf of `Dash`, but I can't be certain it's going to work always - it's not documented.

**Shared `Store` component**

app.py:

```
from dash import html, dcc
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id="store", data=[], storage_type="session"),
        html.H1("Multi Page App Demo: Sharing data between pages"),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    dcc.Link(f"{page['name']}", href=page["path"]),
                )
                for page in dash.page_registry.values()
            ],
        id='navbar'),
        html.Hr(),
        dash.page_container
    ]
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

pages/data.py

```
from dash import html, Input, Output, callback, register_page, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import random

register_page(__name__, path="/")


layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H3("Data input"),
        html.Button("Add row", id="button_id"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id="my-output"),
    ]
)


@callback(
    [Output("store", "data"), Output("my-output", "children")],
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    State("store", "data")
)
def add_data(n_clicks, data):
    if n_clicks:
        new_data = [{"col1": "New row", "col2": random.randint(0, 1000)}]
        return data + new_data, html.Pre(str(new_data))
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

pages/grid.py:

```
from dash import html, dash_table, Input, Output, callback, register_page


register_page(__name__)


layout = html.Div([
    html.H3("Data tables"),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id="table",
        data=[{"name": "Test", "label": "Test"}],
        row_deletable=True,
        column_selectable="single",
        page_size=5,
        persistence=True,
        persisted_props=["columns.name", "data"],
    ),
])


@callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    Input("store", "data"),
)
def add_rows(new_data):
    return new_data

@callback(
    Output("store", "data", allow_duplicate=True),
    Input("table", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_back(new_data):
    return new_data
```

**Using a persistent component feature from `dash_extensions.pages`**

app.py:

```
from dash import html, dcc
from dash_extensions.pages import setup_page_components
from pages.components import NAVBAR_ID
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id="store", data=[], storage_type="session"),
        html.H1("Multi Page App Demo: Sharing data between pages"),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    dcc.Link(f"{page['name']}", href=page["path"]),
                )
                for page in dash.page_registry.values()
            ],
        id=NAVBAR_ID),
        html.Hr(),
        dash.page_container,
        setup_page_components()
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

pages/components.py

```
from dash import dash_table

NAVBAR_ID = "navbar"

data_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        id="table",
        row_deletable=True,
        column_selectable="single",
        page_size=5,
        persistence=True,
        persisted_props=[
            "data",
            "columns.name",
        ]
    )
```

pages/data.py

```
from dash import html, Input, Output, callback, register_page
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import random

register_page(__name__, path="/")


layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H3("Data input"),
        html.Button("Add row", id="button_id"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id="my-output"),
    ]
)


@callback(
    [Output("store", "data"), Output("my-output", "children")],
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks")
)
def add_data(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        new_data = [{"col1": "New row", "col2": random.randint(0, 1000)}]
        return new_data, html.Pre(str(new_data))
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

pages/grid.py

```
from dash import html, Input, Output, callback, register_page, State
from pages.components import data_table


register_page(__name__, page_components=[data_table])


layout = html.Div([
    html.H3("Data tables"),
])


@callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    Input("store", "data"),
    State("table", "data")
)
def add_rows(new_data, old_data):
    if old_data:
        return old_data + new_data
    return new_data
```

Comment: I use exactly (1) all the time, I'm not sure why it shouldn't work. If you create a Store component with session storage it will be persisted and available to whatever page of the application. I usually define all the Store components in app.py and then have multiple pages importing them into the callback to gather data. I think this is exactly the same as your solution.

Comment: @Droid Because of circular dependency. The Store updates table, table updates Store, and we have a cycle. What's breaking the cycle?